# Positioning text inside a Div

Tags: html, text, positioning

I can't figure out how to get the "This is the header" div's text to move down without effecting the rest of the page. When I add padding-top to the header div, it increases the entire div's size. That's not what I want. I just want to move the text down to the middle of the div.

```
<body>


<div id="container">

    <div id="name">
    <h1>Byron Woodfork</h1>
   </div>        

    <div id="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div><!--ends nav div-->


    <div id="header">
    <p>This is the header</p>

    </div><!--ends header div-->

#nav {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #07f50b;

}

#name {
    width: 560px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #06f706;

}

#header {
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #282e34;

}
```

Comment: and where exactly you want to place it?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to set the line-height of your header div to have the same height as the div itself (so line-height: 500px).  This doesn't work as nice if your text takes up more than one line, though.